# Reducing the fall-time of a P-channel MOSFET Follow-up

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switching, biasing

[The original question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691731/reducing-the-fall-time-of-a-p-channel-mosfet?noredirect=1#comment1844353_691731)
[Answer by Simon Fitch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/691880/354770)
[image: Recommended circuit]

Please refer the original question link and the suggested answer by Simon fitch

I have implemented in hardware as it was recommended. I gave 15Vdc supply. Connected the supply to the source, Drain to the load analyser and applied 1A load.
[image: schematic]
[image: Hardware circuit]
[image: Setup]

The results obtained are as follows:- Results for 1KHz, 5KHz, 9KHz
1kHz
[image: 1KHz]

5KHz
[image: 5KHz]

11kHz
[image: 11KHz]
I added 10uF electrolytic and 0.1uF ceramic capacitors close to source terminal and ground. From the pictures, we can see that the ON time is still decreasing. The simulation works fine but in hardware I am not obtaining the desired results. So do you think it is now solely dependent on the mosfet or are am I missing anything in the circuit? I used the same part number(SQM120P10_10M1LGE3) as i didn't had any other better mosfet. Will soon replace it with a better one.

Note: I added two 22ohm,1W resistors in parallel in place of R13(series resistor at the gate terminal). Rest of the resistors are less than 1W through hole resistors. The SMD mosfet is soldered on an already available BARE PCB and the connections are made as shown in the figures.

Comment: Okay. I haven't even read this much but I can see you aren't lazy and you are putting in good time, as well, to document the issue: +1. (The schematic is not oriented very well. But it's not complex, either. So tolerable.)

Comment: Are you trying to use a programmable load instead of the 2 ohm resistor?

Comment: Are the oscillograms gate-source voltages or drain-source voltages?

Comment: +1, try probing the gate. Most likely the MOSFET switches as you intended and what you're seeing is due to the electronic load.

Comment: I am applying load using load analyser. I applied 1A load between drain and ground terminals and recorded the results. But I require minimum 28V pulse with 100KHz frequency with 10% duty cycle and the output load will vary from 2ohm to 10ohm.

Answer (score 0):

> ... drain to the load analyser and applied 1A load.

I see almost the same fall time, ~100μs, in your oscillograms. This tells me that using an active (electronic) load appears to be your problem.

Apparently, you set a substantially long rise time. Once the terminal voltage seen by the electronic load reaches a threshold (usually lower than 1V) the equipment increases the drawn current linearly within a set time (rise time).

If the equipment supports, try to set the rise time to the lowest possible or maybe try with CR (constant resistance) mode, or try with physical resistors as load.

Comment: As I recall, constant resistance mode on electronic loads is generally very slow, as it puts the whole control system of the load into the system response (usually including software components of said control system, not just hardware). Constant-current mode, on the other hand, is usually the fastest as the only active part of the control system is the innermost loop, usually implemented in analog hardware. If you want a constant resistance, just use a resistor.

Comment: @Hearth CR and CP are always slower than CC, yes, but how (very?) slow depends on the equipment, design and implementation. Some of them might be so terrible that you see oscillations, and some of them can be really good even with low input voltages or low currents. It all depends.

Comment: I simply mean to say that a cheap electronic load (I don't recognise the one in the picture) is unlikely to be suitable here in CR mode, though it may work in CC mode.

Comment: @Hearth The load in the picture is [this](https://uk.farnell.com/tenma/72-13210/dc-electronic-load-prog-30a-120v/dp/2848407) which appears to be a re-branded Farnell copy of Korad KEL103 which is a not-well-known-but-makes-hobbyists-happy thing. The specs look promising for a £200 thing. `... is unlikely to be suitable here in CR mode` Who knows? There are lots of cheap but unexpectedly good equipment out there, maybe that's one of those. Anyway, I gave the options to the OP, so whichever works.

Comment: I have tested the same in CR mode. But there is no difference.  Do you think anything else is affecting the output other than programmable load?

Comment: @SahasraVaiishnavi try with physical resistors i.e. bypass the electronic load entirely.

Comment: Yes i will try with Physical resistors. I am facing another issue. The problem is, I am getting a 4V peak-to-peak at the collector of Q10 and  2V peak-to-peak at the gate of the mosfet. And hence, I am not getting the output. What may be the reason for this? Why am I getting 4V peak-to-peak at the collector of Q10?

Comment: The high-level of the pulse is at 15V and low-level of the pulse is at 11V for the pulse wave at the collector of Q10(4V peak-to-peak) 
The high-level of the pulse is at 15V and low-level of the pulse is at 11V for the pulse wave at the gate terminal(2V peak-to-peak)